# Good beginners material for Digital Filter's applications

Tags: reference-request, filters

Can you please suggest some good study material on digital filter's applications. Any good books, articles, video material would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean on digital filters themselves or how and where they are used?

Comment: I found a lot of theory on filter's design, but not their uses. For instance Butterworth's application: http://ignaciomellado.es/blog/Measuring-heart-rate-with-a-smartphone-camera

Comment: You mean like: http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1225797, https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/, http://www.d-filter.ece.uvic.ca/SupMaterials/Slides/DSP-Ch01-S8,9.pdf, http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/53534, http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02477811#page-1

Comment: Cool material, thanks!

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: Please see answer and also explore the Raspberry - Pi link.

Comment: It sounds nice, but I think I'm gonna explore Arduino first. Maybe someone would find interesting this article: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/arduino-vs-raspberry-pi-which-is-the-mini-computer-for-you/

Comment: That is also an excellent choice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Digital Filters*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter) are used in many applications.

Here are some nice examples:

- http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1225797
- http://www.d-filter.ece.uvic.ca/SupMaterials/Slides/DSP-Ch01-S8,9.pdf
- http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/53534
- http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02477811#page-1

One novel way to explore these is to get a [*Raspberry-Pi*](http://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi/) and use the built-in Mathematica to do all sorts of filtering and mathematically based experiments.

Comment: Nice resources!